# Memory leak in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, itext, memory-leak-detector

In our software, we using iTextSharp to generate payment checkbooks
In some case, we need generate 10 000 file in a time, we run it under Windows Services, and then, we have got problem as folow:
**After generate completed, the RAM of service very larger, althrough we have call GC.Collect and release all variables.**

I take a day to resolve it and finaly I found that: The *FontFactoryImp* class in iTextSharp has a hashtable name *fontFamilies*, it holding many memory and never be released. In detail, I see it have many duplicate values !. So, I resolved it by clear that hashtable in finaly by

```
iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.FontImp = new iTextSharp.text.FontFactoryImp();
GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration);
```

and everything is Ok but it look like cheating.

The question is: **Have any wrong or risk in my solution?**

Comment: If the FontFactoryImp object has a Dispose() function, call it (call every Dispose function you can find!). The normal garbage collection will call it but at an indeterminate time in the future.

Comment: Well, in the FontFactoryImp, does not have Dispose() function.

Comment: I think iTextSharp using FontFactoryImp to caching, but it seem to have many duplicate values.

Comment: Are you calling `RegisterDirectory()` or `RegisterDirectories()` in your code?

Comment: Yes, i see this line *iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.RegisterDirectories();* and it called every time open the file. What is wrong ?